# Running server-side code once (at dev & build) then using the data in client-side

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, playwright, nuxtjs3

** **Updated with nitro plugin approach** **

I'm using `Playwright` server-side to get some data from a page that I want to use in my frontend, this the setup using nitro plugin

- Base Project Structure

  ```
  pages
    index.vue
  server
    db
      index.js
    plugins
      playwright.js
    routes
      playwright.js
  ...
  ```
- `server/db/index.js`

  ```js
  export const db = [];
  ```
- `server/routes/playwright.js`

  ```js
  import { db } from '../db';
  export default defineEventHandler(() => db);
  ```
- `server/plugins/playwright.js`

  ```js
  import { chromium } from 'playwright';


  export default defineNitroPlugin(async () => { 
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    // ...
    // some operations goes here
    // and some console logs for tracking progress
    // ...
    db.push(results); // results is the scraped data
  });
  ```

On running `nuxt dev`, the script in `plugins/playwright` starts, opens the browser, scrape the data and store it to `db` **with all my `console.log` logged to the terminal (this is different in prod)**.

When I open local host I get the index page with the fetched data from db with no errors.

However on running `nuxt generate` the CLI runs as usual and I see **only some of the console.logs** printed to terminal as following

```js
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nuxt generate
Nuxi 3.0.0
Nuxt 3.0.0 with Nitro 1.0.0  

WARN  Using experimental payload extraction for full-static output. 
You can opt-out by setting experimental.payloadExtraction to false. 

i Client built in 1666ms
i Building server...  
√ Server built in 581ms
√ Generated public .output/public
i Initializing prerenderer
 Starting Playwright server plugin
⚙️ Read User-specifed options
 Initiating a new page
// There are more console.logs than these three 
i Prerendering 3 initial routes with crawler

  ├─ / (290ms)
  ├─ /200.html (3ms)
  ├─ /404.html (5ms)
  ├─ /_payload.js (2ms)
√ You can now deploy .output/public to any static hosting!
Done in 6.21s.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

On running `nuxt preview` and openning local host I get the index page with a an empty array (the initial value for `db`)

Do I need to somehow force the `generate` command to wait until the nitro plugin finish executing? and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in playwright package not in nuxt itself, after getting playwright to work and using routes the app worked correctly

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this can help, but you can solve this using a "ready" hook:

First, create a file like this (./hooks/hooks.js):

```
export default (nuxtConfig) => ({
    ready: () => {
    // Execute your code here
    }
});
```

Then add it to your nuxt.config.js:

```
import hooks from './hooks/hooks';
export default {
    // Other stuff
    hooks: hooks(this),
    // Other stuff
}
```

Comment: I'll try this but what's `this` in `hooks: hooks(this)` ?

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud You can follow the docs in [Hooks Property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-hooks/)

Comment: After searching I've used a nitro plugin and it works in dev but not production. I've updated the question with more details